# How can I return a file from Controller to view?

Tags: html, perl, mojolicious

I'm trying to return a file from controller to view (more specific a .jpeg) and not the path because I don't want to be seen.

This is my code at the moment:

```
sub get_avatar {
    my $self = shift;
    my $username = $self->stash('id');
    my $home = Mojo::Home->new;
    $home->detect('SuperSecret');
    my $path = $home->child('my', 'path', "$username");
    my $file;
    if (-e $path) {
    $file = "my/path/$username";
    } else {
    $file = "my/path/default.png";
    }
    return $file;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Images you serve should live in a place where they can be accessed by the web server (and no the actual application). That's what _public_ is meant for. If you don't want the images to be easily identifiable, rename them to UUIDs or other random strings, or even an md5 or similar hash of their content, and use that. The alternative is to read the file and have an inline image in your template, but that breaks the user's browser caching.

Comment: There is any chance to return the file from backend? So my variable $file will be the file and not the path.

Comment: Is this about hiding your images from unauthenticated clients? If so use an authenticated  route for your `src= ` attribute and serve with `Mojo::Asset::File`.

Answer (score 2):

The image can be encoded to pass it as a Data URL rather than linking to the file. See the example below of a simple application encoding an image.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use English;
use MIME::Base64;

my $filename = "acorn_PNG37023.png";
## read file as binary data
open( my $png_fh, '<:raw', $filename ) or die "$OS_ERROR";
read $png_fh, my $png_bin_data, -s $png_fh;
close($png_fh);

my $encoded = MIME::Base64::encode($png_bin_data);

get '/' => { 
    text => '<img src="data:image/png;base64,' . $encoded . '" alt="png" />'  
};

app->start;
```